# Firefox zooms to user's location even if locator button isn't clicked when useTracking is true

Tags: arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, geolocation, firefox

When I am in Firefox and go to Esri's example at [LocatorWidget](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=widget_locate) and add `useTracking: true` to the geoLocate definition e.g.

```
  geoLocate = new LocateButton({
    map: map,
    useTracking: true
  }, "LocateButton");
  geoLocate.startup();
```

and click on the locator widget I zoom to my location as expected.  But if I move the map in any way, Firefox zooms me back to the user location, even if I have toggled the locator widget to not track.  IE and Chrome do not behave this way.

Comment: Why was this voted down?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be due to how different browsers implement https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/watchPosition

In a typical "wired" desktop situation, Chrome/IE/Edge only return one single position, while Firefox returns multiple (even if it hasn't changed).

If you switch to for example using the internet via a cellphone connection, all browsers seem to return multiple locations.

Comment: This makes sense since I have found the same problem when people run the code on their phone browsers.